# Problem with burger menu not moving correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with some CSS code that should make a burger menu slide in. Now in the instructions, I followed it said that this part was responsible to make the menu appear from the left but I need it to appear from the right. any help is greatly appreciated,
thank you

```
/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

this is the link to the full menu code: https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just play a bit around with the values. To move the whole thing to the right, change the left value

```
#menuToggle 
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  */ Change this */ left:85%; 
  top:50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

To make the menu move from right to left, change this value from negative to positive in #menu:

```
#menu
{
          transform: translate(100%, 0);
```

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  /* make it look decent enough */
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
left:85%;
  top:50px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover
{
  color: tomato;
}


#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!--    Made by Erik Terwan    -->
<!--   24th of November 2015   -->
<!--        MIT License        -->
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    
    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank"><li>Show me more</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```